# Dynamic show/hide div with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic show/hide javascript that works, as long as i don't make it dynamic and make sure of a parameter. I would appreciate a lot if anyone could help me figure out why the dynamic version doesn't work.

Working code:
**javascript**

```
function togglesDiv(){  
  var catdiv = document.getElementById("addNewCat");  
  if(catdiv.style.display == ""){  
    catdiv.style.display = "none";  
  } else {  
    catdiv.style.display = "";  
  }  
}
```

**html**

```
<span onclick="togglesDiv();">Add new category</span>  
<div id="addNewCat" style="display: none;">  
lalala  
</div>
```

Non working code:
**javascript**

```
function togglesDiv(divsId){  
  var catdiv = document.getElementById("divsId");
  if(catdiv.style.display == ""){  
    catdiv.style.display = "none";  
  } else {  
    catdiv.style.display = "";  
  }  
}
```

**html**

```
<span onclick="togglesDiv(addNewCat);">Add new category</span>  
<div id="addNewCat" style="display: none;">  
lalala  
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variable name wrapped in string delimiters, making it a string literal instead of a variable.  Change

```
var catdiv = document.getElementById("divsId");
```

To

```
var catdiv = document.getElementById(divsId);
```

On the flipside, the call to the function needs the quotes in it's argument (because it should be a string), you can use single quotes to avoid confliction:

```
<span onclick="togglesDiv('addNewCat');">Add new category</span>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  When you add the quotes around divsId, it makes it a string with a value divsId, meaning it is looking for a div with that id.  Without the quotes, it will look for the value of the string variable named divsId

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes:

```
var catdiv = document.getElementById("divsId");
```

Becomes

```
var catdiv = document.getElementById(divsId);
```

You don't have an element with an ID of "divsId".

On a completely unrelated note, you can't be sure that `catdiv.style.display` will always be equal to `""` when it is visibile. There are other styles which cause it to be displayed ('inline', 'block', for example).

A better solution might be:

```
function togglesDiv(divsId){  
  var catdiv = document.getElementById("divsId");
  if(catdiv.style.display === "none"){  
    catdiv.style.display = "";  
  } else {  
    catdiv.style.display = "none";  
  }  
}
```

(And yes, I did mean to put the triple equals `===` in)

Comment: Remember that *element.style.display* is equivalent to inline styles and isn't affected by CSS rules.  If you're in complete control of the script and the markup, you can be fairly certain that `element.style.display == ""` if you haven't already modified it.  That being said, it is better to check against *"none"* than *""*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a div with an ID "divsId" change your code to:

```
   function togglesDiv(divsId){  
      var catdiv = document.getElementById(divsId);
      if(catdiv.style.display == ""){  
        catdiv.style.display = "none";  
      } else {  
        catdiv.style.display = "";  
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for a div called "divsId" rather than the value in the variable divsId.
Remove the speach marks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from 
`var catdiv = document.getElementById("divsId");`
should be 
`var catdiv = document.getElementById(divsId);`

And add quotes:

```
<span onclick="togglesDiv(addNewCat);">Add new category</span>
```

Should be

```
<span onclick="togglesDiv('addNewCat');">Add new category</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved function

```
function toggleDisplay(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!el) return true;
    // feature detect to support IE versions.
    var dis = 'currentStyle' in el ? el.currentStyle.display : el.style.display;
    // toggle display
    el.style.display = /none/i.test(dis) ? '' : 'none';
    // prevent memory leak
    el = null;
}
```

And as mentioned, quotes are needed when writing yucky inline javascript.

```
<span onclick="toggleDisplay('addNewCat')"> ... etc
```

Tbh. pick a js toolkit/library and use it over reinventing the wheel yourself and stop writing inline javascript, your life and happiness will improve substantially if you do =P

Comment: *currentStyle* and *style* aren't the same, so you'll run into inconsistencies between browsers.  *window.getComputedStyle()* is the standards alternative to *currentStyle*.

Comment: ya i use jquery mostly otherwise, but this was just such a small thing in a personal backend system so i didn't see the point in using something bigger.